# Peer to Peer network file transfers

Tags: c#, p2p

I would like to implement a project that would work across the internet.

The scenario is having some files on a server, and clients should update they're files
from the server's folder. But i was thinking of sharing the traffic, i should implement something like peer to peer, so files could shared between clients too! Say client 1 downloaded a file from the server, client 2 and client 3 could download the file from client 1, or client 2 from server and client 3 from client 1, or they could download from both sources!

I guess i should implement a server-client solution. But i hang on the p2p thing that i never
used before and don't know any libraries on the subject. I have some knowledge over TCP protocol but this could serve on direct file transfer from server to client.

I use .NET 3.5 SP1 and C#.

Any suggestions on where to begin searching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look at MonoTorrent. It's a complete library written in C#. It can be found [here](http://projects.qnetp.net/projects/show/monotorrent).

And here's a Code Project article about P2P in C#: [Generic P2P Architecture, Tutorial and Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/Generic_P2P_Architecture.aspx?msg=767759)